# Unable to install Cisco Any Connect V3 on Windows 7

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I tried to install Cisco Any Connect V3 to connect to GM VPN but no luck.
The first time, I installed this successfully. Then, I uninstalled it. Today, I re-installed it and the error occurred:

```
"There is a problem with Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor".
```

I found some solutions on Google and they might damage Windows OS because it requires to change the REGISTRY.
For more information, I can install successfully on another machine that run windows 7 too.
Please help me to solve this problem. I hope it can be solved as soon as possible.

Comment: Does the install log give clues on what actually went wrong ? Invoke `msiexec` from the command line passing `/L*V` parameters.

Comment: MSI (s) (88:E0) [22:26:25:656]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=kdf_acsock64_Install,ActionType=3090,Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\VACon64.exe,Target=kdf -install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\\" acsock,)
CustomAction kdf_acsock64_Install returned actual error code 1062 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

Comment: MSI (s) (88:E0) [22:26:27:012]: Product: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action kdf_acsock64_Install, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\VACon64.exe, command: kdf -install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\\" acsock

Comment: Please help me to identify root cause :(

Comment: Looks like Driver installation is failing. Launch "Device Manager" and check "Network adapters". If there is any Cisco AnyConnect adapter listed there, right click and uninstall it. And then try to run installer again. BTW, is this a physical machine or a VM ?

Comment: @Mahesh: This is physical machine. BTW, there is no Driver related to Cisco AnyConnect adapter in the list. :(

Comment: Can you please share "setupapi.dev.log, setupapi.setup.log" files present in `C:\Windows\inf` directory ? Upload them to some free file sharing servers available and give the link.